# Using WndProc and mciSendString in order to determine if an audio file has reached its end

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a simple media player, right now I'm able to play a song and load a number of songs to create a playlist, the problem is when one song ends, the program won't proceed to the next song.

```
    public void Play(int songNumber, Form f)
    {
            Load(Songs[songNumber]);
            string Command = "play MediaFile notify";
            mciSendString(Command, null, 0, f.Handle);
    }

    private void PlayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int length = AudioPlayer.PlaylistLength;
        for (int PlayLoopcnt = 0; PlayLoopcnt < length;)
        {
            Player.Play(PlayLoopcnt, this);
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg == MM_MCINOTIFY)
        {
            PlayLoopcnt++;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m); 
   }
```

I have an AudioPlayer class which handles all the methods for the amedia player such as play, stop etc...

WndProc is located in the form code, I would be happy if anybody can point out what I'm doing wrong and if it's even the correct approach.

Comment: The Click event handler is wrong, it can't use a for-loop.  It instead needs to set PlayLoopcnt = 0 and only start the first song.  Then WndProc needs to increment, as it does, and call Play() so the next song is activated.

Comment: That worked, Thanks!